# How can i fix the issue for context menu for Treeview click

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

My code for opening a context menu on Right-click for a treeview is as follows

```
private void contextMenu_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt16(tvwACH.SelectedNode.Tag) == 1)
        {
            contextMenu.Items.Add(New);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Remove);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Saveas);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Save);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(addEntry);
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt16(tvwACH.SelectedNode.Tag) == 2)
        {
            contextMenu.Items.Add(New);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Remove);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Saveas);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Save);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(addEntry);
            New.Text = "Add FileHeader";
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt16(tvwACH.SelectedNode.Tag) == 3)
        {
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(New);
            contextMenu.Items.Add(Save);
            contextMenu.Items.Add(Saveas);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Remove); //Added later
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(addEntry);
        }
        if (tvwACH.SelectedNode.Parent != null)
        {
            string str = tvwACH.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString().Substring(10);
            if (str == "BatchHeader")
            {
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(New);
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(Save);
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(Remove);
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(Saveas);
                contextMenu.Items.Add(addEntry);
            }
        }
```

and also mouse down for treeview as follows

```
 private void tvwACH_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            contextMenu.Show(tvwACH, e.Location);
        }
        location = e.Location;
    }
```

But this getting opened every where on tree-view control but i only need it to be opened when i click on Nodes of my tree-view.

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you only want the context menu to be displayed when the user right-clicks on a node, you need to include some logic in your `MouseDown` event hander to verify that the click event occurred over a node.**

You can determine the node that is located at a particular point using the [`HitTest` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6sb88bz.aspx) provided by the `TreeView`. For example, you could modify your current `MouseDown` event handler to include the following code:

```
private void tvwACH_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (tvwACH.HitTest(e.Location).Node != null)
        {
            contextMenu.Show(tvwACH, e.Location);
        }
    }
}
```